# Nginx and PHP-FPM blocking folder with contains "php" in the name

Tags: magento, nginx, php

I'm developing an eCommerce with Magento using Nginx and PHP-FPM.

I have a folder called "boletophp" and the site is trying to access this link: "my.store/skin/boletophp/imagens/logobb.jpg" and the Nginx rewrites the link to "my.store/skin/boletophp/".

I changed the folder name to "boleto" and the image loaded successfully, but the module doesn't work properly. So the folder name need to be "boletophp".

This is my.store config file:

```
server {
    server_name my.store;
    access_log /srv/www/my.store/logs/access.log;
    error_log /srv/www/my.store/logs/error.log;
    root /srv/www/my.store/public_html;

    location / {
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
    }

    location ~ ^/(app|includes|lib|media/downloadable|pkginfo|report/config.xml|var)/ { internal; }
    location /var/export/ { internal; }
    location /. { return 404; }
    location @handler { rewrite / /index.php; }
    location ~* .php/ { rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last; }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        client_max_body_size 2048M;
        expires off;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/www/my.store/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
        fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
    }

    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
        expires 30d;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }
}
```

Versions:

```
  Nginx: 1.6.2
    PHP: 5.6.5
Magento: 1.9.1
```

Kind regards,

William Bertan

Comment: Not sure about this, but try replacing `location ~* .php/ { rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last; }` by `location ~* \.php/ { rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last; }`

Comment: GREAT! Post an answer for me give to you the right answer! Thank You!

Comment: I'm grad it worked! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing the line:

```
location ~* .php/ { rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last; }
```

by

```
location ~* \.php/ { rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last; }
```

I hope it helps!